# Conditional Statement with a "wildcard"

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, wildcard

In table A, there’s columns 1 and 2.

- Column 1 is unique id’s like (‘A12324’) and column 2 is blank for now.
- I want to fill the value of column 2 with Yes if the id starts with A, and else No.

Is any one familiar with how I can maybe use a left for this?

I tried this but my error read that left is not defined.

```
 TableA.loc[TableA['col1'] == left('A',1), 'hasAnA'] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: `TableA['col1'][1] == 'A'`

Comment: I don't think ```left()``` is a defined method in this context, but I posted an answer that works without that. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you @JohannesAck! That was exactly right.

Comment: Would you mind adding how I would add multiple conditions to one statement. Say if I were trying to get an exact string match and I also wanted to exclude nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`pd.Series.str.startswith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) method:

```
>>> frame = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ['A12342', 'B123123231'], 'colB': False})
>>> condition = frame['colA'].str.startswith('A')
>>> frame.loc[condition, 'colB'] = 'Yes'
>>> frame
         colA  colB
0      A12342   Yes
1  B123123231  False
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add multiple conditions? like 'colA' starts with A, 'colA' ends with B, and 1 more? I'm attempting 3 conditions using your method and it is unsuccessful.

Comment: @Lauren You can define multiple conditions similarly to the condition in the code example, and then combine them by using the `&` operator: `combined_cond = condA & condB & condC`

Comment: I did that like so and got an error about my syntax right at the and.                        'Condition = ((df['status']=='Live') and
(df['name'].str.startswith('A') and
(df['true']==1))

df.loc[Condition, 'EmptyCol'] = 'True' '

Comment: You have to use `&`, not `and`